# NSXMLParser shreds umlauts (ä, ö, ü)

Tags: iphone, xml, cocoa-touch, nsxmlparser

I use NSXMLParser for parsing XML documents of a server. They are encoded as UTF8.
My problem is, that NSXMLParser breaks at umlauts (ä, ö, ü) and starts a new element.

For example:

Lösen -- NSXMLParser ---> L + ösen

How do I get NSXMLParser to read my umlaut words completely, as every other word.

Regards

Comment: Do you mean that <Lösen> becomes <L><ösen>?  Or that the parser is returning two text nodes, "L" and "ösen"?

Comment: The parser gives me two strings for foundCharacters: 
So the delegate is foundCharacters: is called for "L" and "ösen". I want the parser to send the delegate only once for the complete string.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Sorry but based on your comment on the original question (foundCharacters receiving the text in two calls) the parser is behaving perfectly well.  See the "Discussion" section for the parser:foundCharacters: method quoted below:

> The parser object may send the delegate several parser:foundCharacters: messages to report the characters of an element. Because string may be only part of the total character content for the current element, you should append it to the current accumulation of characters until the element changes.

As you can see the parser is free to pass your delegate the characters in as many chunks as it sees fit.

Answer (score 3):

`foundCharacters:` is not delinited by tags, you need to concatentate the characters passed in unti lthe next call to `didEndElement`.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into that issue with Spanish characters  in this line:

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string

I'm sure if you get the found characters section working well with the `didEndElement` function, you'll be fine.